# Create symbolic link in SD card Android

Tags: java, android, filesystems, symlink

I want to keep track of the files which get downloaded through my app. For the downloads, I want to use the default downloads directory. But I want to keep a soft link in a separate place in SD card so that if the original file is moved I can still keep track of that.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: And why can't you use provided api: [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) ?

Comment: In Android, doesn't the SD card usually contain a vfat filesystem (which can't do symlinks)?

Comment: Where is your default downloads directory?

Comment: Jermaine Xu: /sdcard/Downloads